# mapping values are not allowed in this context

Tags: xubuntu, network-manager, netplan

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  wifis:
   wlan0:
    dhcp4:no
    dhcp6:no
    addresses: [10.10.10.1/24]
    gateway4: 10.10.10.254
```

Error message:
line 8 column 13: mapping values are not allowed in this context

What are mapping values?

Comment: I don't know all the terminology, but I believe you need at least one space after the colon in each `key: value` pair i.e. `dhcp4: no` and `dhcp6: no`

Comment: I won't have access to that computer till tomorrow but the error is appearing on the addresses line, not the dhcp lines.

Comment: line 8 of the file you've pasted is certainly the dhcp6: line, not the addresses: line; the comment line counts as a line.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the indentation used within the .yaml file

In your example there is a two whitespace inndentation after 'network:' before 'version: 2' but after 'wifis:' and subsequently only one additional space is used as an indent.  you can use either/or but not both, so the following will work:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  wifis:
    wlan0:
      dhcp4:no
      dhcp6:no
      addresses: [10.10.10.1/24]
      gateway4: 10.10.10.254
```

You MUST keep the indentations uniform

Answer (score 0):

A YAML [mapping](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#mapping//) is defined as:

> #### Mapping
>
> The content of a mapping node is an unordered set of key:
>   value node pairs, with the restriction that each of the keys is
>   unique.

Note that:

> Mappings use a colon **and space** (“: ”) to mark each key: value pair.

(emphasis mine). So if you omit the space between the key and value

```
foo:
  bar:baz
  bam: "xyz"
```

it produces the error

> (): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 3 column 6

whereas

```
foo: 
  bam: xyz
  bar: baz
```

is valid YAML. The error appears to occur in the valid line because the previous line (the "context") is broken.

You can try it for example at [www.yamllint.com](http://www.yamllint.com/)

Comment: www.yamllint.com corrected all the issues I was having.